# App is taking the assets when app deeplink is passed to the browser using appium

Tags: android, google-chrome, automation, appium, android-deep-link

I am doing an automation of an android mobile app, there is a scenario where I am trying to use deeplink of where that **deeplink** should open the app in device and download some assets. As a process I am first opening my app and then I just login to the app then I am just doing `driver.quit();` then I am opening the chrome app using appium and doing `sendkeys()` in url bar of chrome but this just opening the app as logged in but I din't find the assets downloaded. If the same thing I do manually I can see the assets are downloaded in the app.

ExampleCode:

```
chromeSearch2.sendKeys("myproduct.page.link/3CCjN8sdwPZAuhaf9");
TouchAction a2 = new TouchAction(driver);
a2.tap (350, 230).perform();
```

Also some can suggest different approach for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after a lot of research. 
Instead of the driver.quit() and then starting chrome with new driver I just changed the same driver from my app to chrome as

```
driver.startActivity("com.android.chrome", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
```

After doing this if I pass the deep link I am able to get the assets.

This I got in this one of the stackoverflow answer.